# bootstrap 5 carousel is not responsive and text missing

Tags: frontend, carousel, bootstrap-5

I am new to web devolopment, i want to add carousel in my project so i have copied this basic template from bootstrap docs, in desktop view it working but in mobile view it showing a unwanted black space and captions missing, please some one help
I am new to web devolopment, i want to add carousel in my project so i have copied this basic template from bootstrap docs, in desktop view it working but in mobile view it showing a unwanted black space and captions missing, please some one help

[image]

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">


<section class="home">
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-indicators">
<button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
<button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
<button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
</div>
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item active">
<img src="{% static 'img/slide-1.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100 h-auto" alt="...">
<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
<h5>First slide label</h5>
<p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img src="{% static 'img/slide-2.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100 h-auto" alt="...">
<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
<h5>Second slide label</h5>
<p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img src="{% static 'img/slide-3.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100 h-auto" alt="...">
<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
<h5>Third slide label</h5>
<p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
</button>
<button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
</button>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

custom.css

```
.carousel-item {
height: 24rem;
background: #000;
}

.carousel-item>img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
max-width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0.5;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
height: 500px;
}

.carousel-caption{
bottom: 25%;
}
.carousel-caption h5{
font-size: 30px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.carousel-caption p{
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make testing easier i added some grey color to the background (you can remove it later).

What I think you are missing, is to add the Bootstrap scripts, you can see the code for an example.

[Here you have](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction) how to do it, from Bootstrap documentation.

[image: Bootstrap Scripts]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

>>>>>>>>>> SCRIPTS HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
>>>>>>>>>>> UP HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

  <title></title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: gray">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="IMAGE 1">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="IMAGE 2">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="IMAGE 3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Regarding your question about "where" to put the text, after the images will be ok.

Here you have a working example (from one of my portfolio projects):

```html
  <!-- Testimonials -->
  <section id="testimonials" class="colored-section">
    <div id="testimonials-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active container-fluid">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item container-fluid">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonials-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonials-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
</html>
```

Please, mark the answer as accepted ;)

Comment: thanks for your answer it is responsive now but where shoud i add text on it, i have tried 'h5' and 'p' tags  after img tag but again they are missing in mobile view

Comment: yes, iam using 3 script tags as you mentioned

Comment: I already edited the answer with new info and the answer to your previous question ;)

Answer (score 1):

below things worked for me

```
<div class="carousel-caption  d-block">
```

Instead of

```
<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
```

read here [display properties](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)